# R: Finding column names that match substrings of row names

Tags: r, substring

I am trying to extract a value from a certain column, where that column name matches the first 3 letters of the corresponding row name. I think its easiest to explain with an example:
Matrix 1

> BVT IPL LHC MDC
>    100 200 300 400

Matrix 2

> Col1 Col 2
>   BVTIPL 100/200
>   IPLBVT  200/100
>   LHCIPL  300/200
>   ...   ...
>   MDCBVT 400/100

In the above, I am taking the left 3 characters of Matrix 2 row name, finding the corresponding column name and dividing the value in that column by the value in the column corresponding to the rightmost 3 characters and placing that value in the corresponding row of Matrix 2.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `?substr` and a named vector:

```
lookupValues <- c(BVT=100, IPL=200, LHC=300, MDC=400)

df <- data.frame(col1=c("BVTIPL", "IPLBVT", "LHCIPL", "MDCBVT"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$col2 <- lookupValues[substr(df$col1, 1, 3)]/lookupValues[substr(df$col1, 4, 6)]
df
#    col1 col2
#1 BVTIPL  0.5
#2 IPLBVT  2.0
#3 LHCIPL  1.5
#4 MDCBVT  4.0
```